# What reg exp i should use to match next pattern in .htaccess?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to use this rule:

```
RewriteRule   ([^\?\.]+)\.html?$  index.php?mode=$1 [QSA]
```

But except google webmaster files like - google12345abcde.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative lookbehind like this to avoid `google12345abcde.html:

```
RewriteRule ^((?!google12345abcde)[^.]+)\.html?$ index.php?mode=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex should match the name of your google webmaster files :

```
google\d{5}[a-z]{5}.html
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i used anubhava advice.